# Query Builder reading conditional like a column - Unknown column in field list

Tags: codeigniter, query-builder

I have a MySQL expression that uses a conditional IF statement. As a MySQL expression, it returns TRUE or FALSE, but when I use it in CodeIgniter's query builder, I get an error. The error suggests that the outcome of the conditional is reading like a column, but how can I fix this? Thanks.

MySQL:

```
SELECT
    positions.max_vol AS attendee_limit,
    COUNT(users_positions.user_id) AS total_attendees,
    IF(COUNT(users_positions.user_id) < positions.max_vol
            OR positions.max_vol IS NULL,
        TRUE,
        FALSE) AS result
FROM
    positions
        INNER JOIN
    users_positions ON positions.id = users_positions.position_id
WHERE
    positions.id = 16
        AND users_positions.calendar_date = '2016-09-05'
```

Function:

```
private function check_attendee_limit($pos_id = NULL, $date = NULL)
{
    $this->db->select('positions.max_vol, COUNT(users_positions.user_id), IF(COUNT(users_positions.user_id) < positions.max_vol OR positions.max_vol IS NULL, TRUE, FALSE)'); 
    $this->db->from('positions');
    $this->db->join('users_positions', "positions.id = users_positions.position_id", 'inner');
    $this->db->where('positions.id', $pos_id);
    $this->db->where('users_positions.calendar_date', $date);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result(); // return the rows selected
}
```

Error:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'TRUE' in 'field list'

SELECT `positions`.`max_vol`, COUNT(users_positions.user_id), IF(COUNT(users_positions.user_id) < positions.max_vol OR positions.max_vol IS NULL, `TRUE`, FALSE)
FROM `positions`
INNER JOIN `users_positions` ON `positions`.`id` = `users_positions`.`position_id`
WHERE `positions`.`id` = '15'
AND `users_positions`.`calendar_date` = '2016-09-05'

Filename: models/projects/Calendar_model.php

Line Number: 141
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CI adds backticks - which means you've to prevent CI from escaping your select

Try this instead

```
$this->db->select('positions.max_vol, COUNT(users_positions.user_id), IF(COUNT(users_positions.user_id) < positions.max_vol OR positions.max_vol IS NULL, TRUE, FALSE)', false);
```

If you are worry about security - in your case it doesn't matter because you don't use any user input in your select query.

You can find more informations about the Query Builder [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=select#CI_DB_query_builder::select)

Comment: Ah, you're totally right. I saw those back ticks in the error, but it didn't click that TRUE shouldn't have been escaped like that. Thanks for the explanation.